# UITableView receive parameter

Tags: ios, uitableview

UITableView(A) and if select one cell of this tableview, it will push to another view(B). If press the BACK button in view(B), it will run this pushBack function:

```
    - (void)pushBack
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

and I want to send a parameter to view(A).The Parameter is used to determine the need to refresh the view(A). How should I do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want to ask two questions, please ask two separate questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is a bug in the simulator. If you want to show your Default.png when the app returns, you have two choices. The first is to set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your Info.plist. However, this will require you to save and load your application state rather than let multitasking do the work for you. The alternative is to overlay your application with your Default.png in `-applicationWillResignActive:` and remove it in `-applicationDidBecomeActive:`, much like Dropbox does if you enable a passcode lock.
2. Implement a method called `-(void)willBecomeVisible:(MyParameterType *)parameter` (your parameter may not be a pointer though). Then in `-pushBack`, before you pop the view controller, do the following:

...

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];  
NSUInteger count = [viewControllers count];  
if (count >= 2) { // Ensures we will not have an out of bounds exception
    UIViewController *viewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:count-2]; // Gets the view controller that will become visible
    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(willBecomeVisible:)]) { // In case this view controller was pushed from a different view controller  
        [(MyTableViewAController *)viewController willBecomeVisible:myParameter];  
    } else {  
        NSLog(@"View controller about to become visible does not respond to -willBecomeVisible:");  
    }  
} else {  
    NSLog(@"Not enough view controllers on the navigation stack!");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, in order to be able to show the splash image when returning from background, you have to define your application as unable to run in the background. This is done by changing the "Application does not run in background" flag in the info.plist to YES.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up about the [Model-View-Controller](http://www.google.com/search?q=model%20view%20controller) design pattern, it will be very useful to you in iOS development.

In general a controller should not directly tell a different controller's view that it needs to refresh. It is the responsibility of `ViewControllerA` to update its view. However, controllers can talk to each other to notify about state changes in the models (or this can be done via the models themselves).

In this case probably the simplest solution would be to have your `ViewControllerB` send a message to `ViewControllerA` - so you should define an interface on `ViewControllerA` and pass a reference of `ViewControllerA` into `ViewControllerB` when it is created so that you can call it when you want. For example:

In `ViewControllerA`...

```
- (void)stateChanged
{
    // Code to handle the change and update the view if it's visible.
    // Alternatively, just set a BOOL flag here and then check it in
    // viewWillAppear so that the view-update only happen later on when
    // the view is actually about to appear.
}
```

In your `pushBack` method within `ViewControllerB`...

```
- (void)pushBack
{
    [viewControllerA stateChanged];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

You can pass whatever extra values you want into `stateChanged` - this is just an example. A cleaner way is to do this using delegates or by observing the model itself from the controllers, but I think this is easier to understand while you're learning MVC and how to best isolate and de-couple the M, V, and C.